# AJAX success function called successfully but does not update page properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have the code section below which is a simple AJAX call to retrieve a JSON string from a .ASMX VB .NET Web Method.  On success, it calls the createList function below, which should take the values in the JSON string (now parsed and formatted) and add them as new list items.

My issue is that the page does not update with the new list items, even though the callback function is successful.  The loop executes, data is received and I have already tested with alerts just to make sure I'm not going crazy.

When I use the exact same line (substituting test data for the JSON string) to append my new list items, everything works fine.

As a side note for anyone that might be wondering why I believe I have to use this methodology:
It is important that I call the AJAX function the way I do, so I may pass multiple parameters to the function when I build the list.  The other parameters allow me to specifically find which element is active in my user control.

I am relatively new to using AJAX as well.  I hope I was able to explain everything clearly.

Thanks!

```
function getPcList(activeRow, activeTd) {

    var row = $(activeRow).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: "AJAXWebService.asmx/getPartnerColleges",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
           createList(data, activeRow, activeTd); 
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

function createList(data, activeRow, td) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + data.d + ")"));
    var json = $.parseJSON(obj);

    var row = $(activeRow).attr("id");
    var newtd = $(td).attr("id");

    for (i = 0; i < json.length - 1; i++) {
        $("#"+row+ "#" + newtd + " > #list > #thelist")
                      .append("<li id='listitem'" + i + 
                      "' style='width:100%; z-index:300; position:relative' onclick='txtAppend($(this).parents().eq(2))'>" + 
                      json[i] + "</li>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put alert msg just before calling createlist, then another alert after it...  If the second alert isnot fired then ur createList method has a bug

Comment: You shouldn't need to parse the data again jQuery does that for you when you provide a datatype.

Comment: @stackunderflow As I mentioned, I have used alerts already to determine if the methods were being executed.  As I've also said, I used a debugger as well to make sure everything runs.

Comment: Ok so now its the createList method issue. My ugly tracking way is to use many alerts after each line inside the method, and when an alert isnt triggered i can spot the line above it and be confident that this line is the source of troubles

Comment: Also make sure that ur json object is well formed and not having escaped chars

Answer (score 1):

If the string returned from the server is a JSON, as indicated by the `dataType` field of the `$.ajax()` call, you shouldn't need to use `JSON.stringify()` and `eval()`. You should be able to parse the string directly with `$.parseJSON()`.